# Can I take advantage of student discounts with Indian airlines if just passed out from college?

Tags: air-travel, budget, india, regulations, paperwork

Within the next few months, I have to fly to Hyderabad for a job. My college will have finished by then. It will have finished in July precisely. But officially my Identity card doesn't expire until August.

So can I use this ID card as a proof of me being a student?

Also if I can manage a bona fide letter from my college, will the airline company consider it?

Since I have never travelled via an air-plane before, I am ignorant about the customs.

Also, how should I proceed with booking a ticket on-line on student booking scheme?

Comment: Also see: [Best deals for students booking international flight tickets from India](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10600/108)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is a domestic flight within India that you're talking about.

Most Indian airlines do not offer an online booking facility for student discount tickets. You either need to go to airline booking offices or get it booked through an authorised travel agent depending on the airline, details of which are available on airline websites. As far as I know, only the two full-service airlines remaining in India - Air India and Jet Airways - do student discounts on tickets and they aren't that deep discounts. You may just find that getting a ticket with a low-cost airline - which don't do  student discounts - could be cheaper. In case you *are* eligible for a student discount, as long as your student ID is valid, it does not matter when you graduate.

Also, since this is a domestic flight you won't have to go through passport control anyway. Even if it was an international flight, student discount tickets are not marked in any way - it's just priced differently - so you wouldn't have to explain to passport control why you have a student ticket. Besides, many students do internships so it's a realistic scenario that a student can have a job too.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, as long as the ID stating you are a student is valid, **and** your status hasn't changed, you can claim student benefits.

An airplane is just another mode of transport. So if the airline that you wish to travel with has such a student scheme, then your student ID should be enough of a proof for them, but again, they are the only ones who can confirm this.

Regarding your query as to how to proceed with booking via the scheme, that is something you will have to find out yourself as firstly you have not mentioned which airline you are planning on flying with, and secondly, if there does exist such a scheme that the airline subscribes to, it should be mentioned on their website, or at worst, info can be obtained by calling their Customer Service.

---

I would also like to state that I believe this is not a question fit for [travel.se], and I have flagged it as such. But if it is ok'd by the Mods, then my answer stands true to the best of my knowledge!

Comment: I may be wrong here but I heard they ask for reasons in airport why am I going there (_maybe specific to international flights, but still need to clarify_)? So if I say job and use a student scheme, would not that be a hypocrisy?

Comment: no, don't worry about any questions being asked.